# eror maximum message size WCF

Tags: xml, wcf

trabajo con un servicio WCF utlizando basicHttpBinding y me aparece el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el cual no he podido resolver, este es mi Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
             maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>


  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SIFP_GFC" connectionString="Dsn=sifp_desarrollo"
        providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

podrian ayudarme y decirme que hago mal?

Answer (score 0):

> Cambia el valor de la propiedad *`maxBufferSize`* en tu archivo de
>   configuración - *`web.config`*.
>
> **[Fuente #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/884248/4092887)** o **[Fuente #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19564171/4092887)**.

Comment: el valor maximo que propone la respuesta de Fuente #2 ya lo tengo establecido en el Web.config del servicio

Comment: @PabloMayora, ok, _eso no lo mencionas en tu pregunta_ :) te recomiendo ver esta [otra respuesta en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35847053/4092887) _o la respuesta aceptada, que es diferente_ o buscar `maxreceivedmessagesize max value web.config`. El mensaje de error dice que puedes cambiar el valor de `maxreceivedmessagesize`. Si has hecho alguna otra modificación, debes mencionarlo en tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: si, por eso agregue el web.config del WCf, igualmente se resuelve agregando la seccion <bindings> al cliente que consume el servicio